# streaming insert in bigquery python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

The python SDK's [`Client.insert_rows`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.insert_rows.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.insert_rows) is documented as

> Insert rows into a table via the streaming API.
>
> See
>   https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll

But when I tried to use it with large data that *needs* to be streamed, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 15, in <module>
    exit(main())
  File "demo.py", line 12, in main
    client.insert_rows(table, rows)
  File "google/cloud/bigquery/bigquery_future/client.py", line 1213, in insert_rows
    return self.insert_rows_json(table, json_rows, **kwargs)
  File "google/cloud/bigquery/bigquery_future/client.py", line 1293, in insert_rows_json
    data=data)
  File "google/cloud/bigquery/bigquery_future/client.py", line 301, in _call_api
    return call()
  File "google/api_core/retry.py", line 246, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "google/api_core/retry.py", line 163, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "google/cloud/core_future/_http.py", line 279, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquer
y/v2/projects/myproject/datasets/mydataset/tables/mytable/insertAll:
Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10915700 bytes.
```

Digging into the code, it definitely does two passes on the data (which I've carefully yielded from a generator) before sending a POST http request to the REST API mentioned in the documentation. That API specifies a single JSON object as body, which isn't a streamable format, and I don't see any allowance for streaming in that endpoint at all.

What am I missing? Do the SDK devs have some definition of streaming that's wholly different from mine? How is there a size limit on a streaming API?

Comment: If you have large request sizes, maybe it would be better to use a load job instead. Otherwise the [streaming limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts) apply.

Comment: I feel like you've misunderstood. The large request is my problem, rather than a requirement; I have a stream of data and when I hand it to the API, it's all gone into a single synchronous request. That's not what I expected, given the documentation shown above.

Comment: You wrote, "I tried to use it with large data," which sounds like it is the problem. The streaming API is intended for frequent, small requests, rather than one large one. You probably need to split up the data and send just one (or a handful) of rows with each request.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's large in total, but quite small per-second. These questions still stand though: What am I missing? Do the SDK devs have some definition of streaming that's wholly different from mine? How is there a size limit on a streaming API?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard is right, you are probably hitting the [HTTP requests size limit](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts) (10 MB). I would say that with ` Client.insert_rows()` you are sending everything expecting it to stream it in chunks. Could you add some snippet to check if that's the case?

Comment: regarding your questions, no, the definition of streaming is the same as always with no tricks attached. I sent you the limits for streaming in the previous comment.

Comment: @Iñigo Yes you are right. In the Python sdk doc it says it uses the streaming API, and in many other places the streaming interface is described as "insert row by row". So when it came time to insert I passed a generator object (the Python idiom for streams) as the rows argument. The generator represents all my data (small per second but large in total) but I expected a streaming API to behave correctly with streaming input, rather than eagerly gobbling all input into a list before sending a single RPC.

Comment: @Iñigo You say that the API is truly streaming, but how can a POST of JSON possibly support streaming? You could allow long-lived connections, but then the server would need a partial-json parser which seems insane. You could allow nd-json or chunked encoding, but I don't find evidence of any of this in the API doc:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll

Comment: Use a *for* to send the rows to BQ in chunks, if not you are gonna hit the HTTP limit.

Comment: If the data you are sending through the JSON is bigger than the limit, you are gonna hit that limit.

Comment: As ElliottBrossard and Iñigo have said, the streaming API expects small requests (i.e. one row at a time or a few at a time). If you pass it the generator representing your whole data, you are essentially trying to send all rows in a single request and hit the HTTP limit.